# W8 question - regarding contract work in the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, self-employment

I'm Canadian and used to work in the US randomly on visa.    Now I reside full time in Canada and am doing some contract work in the US.   They have asked me to complete a W9 but I do not have a visa so I'm thinking a W8 is the right one?   Not sure what a W8BEN is either.